# How to clear all textboxes on a page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, textbox

I have a page with a whole lot of asp.net textboxes `asp:TextBox`. I want to have a clear button which will clear the text from all the textBoxes. The textBoxes are all within their own usercontrol. How could this be done?

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type='Reset' value='clear'/>
```

Will reset all the text fields inside that particular form when clicked.

Comment: Suffers from the issue as noted by @Harsh in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<input type="reset" />` to do this..

Altenately you can assign a cssclass to each textbox and use jQuery to clear them.

Comment: this is good to clear the TextBox but it would only clear the values to last values of the postback... Means if user writes 'myvalue in 'TextBox and then click the submit button and the postback occurs then user again writes 'myanothervalue' then click the reset button then it would only reset the TextBox to 'myvalue' not empty it and also it would reset entire form not the TextBox only...

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is your friend:

```
$("#theButton").click(function() {
  $("[type=text]").val("");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearControls();

    }
    private void ClearControls()
    {
        foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in c.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

on the clear button event use this

```
textBox1.Clear();
```

and for a label you could use this

```
label1.Text = "";
```

it's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Using this method, we can clear the text stored in a textbox easily

```
protected void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearInputs(Page.Controls);
}
void ClearInputs(ControlCollection ctrls)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
            ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
        ClearInputs(ctrl.Controls);
    }
}
```